# Counting the number of words in Texstudio?

Tags: texstudio, word-count

How to count the number of words of a document compiled in Texstudio? Is there exist any way to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Note: I am using Windows 10, Miktex 2.9 and editor is Texstudio 2.11

Comment: Try `Tools -> Analyze Text`

Comment: An alternative, if Analyze Text in Texstudio doesn't cover your needs, could also be to use [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/) which is a Perl script (ie requires Perl installed), also available on the site as a web service.

Comment: Duplicated of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215692/103431

Comment: @divenex Nope, it's not the duplicate question. Its a useful question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, as noted by [@Troy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117534/troy), the only tools native to TexStudio fall under:

```
Tools -> Analyse Text
```

Some requests have been made such as [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/372/) to implement something closer to a Microsoft Word's status bar words count.

[tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215692/](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215692/is-there-a-direct-way-to-get-word-count-in-texstudio) also shows a manually scripted method of getting a word count.