# LaTex word count

Tags: word-count

Does anybody know how can I count the word number in LaTeX file or even the pdf? Since in LaTeX there is an option in tools analyze text, however it also considers the begin end and everything inside and I cannot separate them one by one.

Comment: Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215692/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48498/35864

Answer (score 1):

I use texcount (https://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/). I found it to be quite accurate.
The online interface is handy or you can download a perl script which is easily linked with emacs (see this: https://superuser.com/questions/125027/word-count-for-latex-within-emacs).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any possibility to hack your article or work by using these online applications?

Comment: You can edit text in the online form but that is probably not very convenient if you have to do a lot of editing. It depends what you use to wirte latex. Check the FAQ and download pages for suggestions on how to integrate the perl script in your workflow.